# Azure Functions .Net5 streaming response C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, streaming, httpresponse, .net-5

I am struggling to find a way of streaming data back using HttpResponseData.

Here is a simplified attempt:

```
var response = httpRequestData.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Headers.Add("content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
var stream = response.Body;
for (var i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
{
   await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some chunked data"));
}
return response;
```

Runs locally/dev environment fine. In Azure it returns an RPC Exception -> OutOfMemoryException. I can see why, but cannot see examples / documentation how it can be done successfully.

In .Net Core 3.1, I could use: (excuse the semi-pseudo code)

```
loop
  request.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(...)
return new EmptyResult();
```

I could stream 100's of MBs of data successfully using this approach in .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: The .NET 5 code you posted writes to the stream and *then* returns the response - so it's buffering in memory and not streaming. The .NET 3.1 code you posted writes to the existing response body, so it's streaming. Why not just use the same approach with .NET 5?